# Blueprism - Not able to spy elements

Tags: blueprism

I am using Blueprism to launch a URL in browser to spy it. I am able to launch the URL using the application modeller, but not able to spy it. The "Identify" option itself does not appear in blue prism. What is the problem and what is the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spying a web application, key things to note for your application modeler;
1. your application modeler must be a "Browser-Based Application"
2. Launching from an executable or attaching to one. (Assuming you are launching from an executable from your question)
3. Specify url.

From your question. you are able to launch the browser from the application modeler. the most possible problem is you missing step 1 as mentioned above. Confirm your application modeler is specified as "Browser-Based Application"

Answer (score 0):

Check a few things : is your modeler attached to the browser, are you in the right mode (for ease of use I would recommend using IE in HTML mode), and if that doesn't work try accessibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try these simple steps:

1. Close the browser application and let the Blue Prism open your browser.
2. Try testing your object in Object Studio.
3. Now open your application modeler and launch. Check and you will find the  identify option appeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting the "Identify" button that means you are not attached or connected to the application, regardless of how the application was launched (i.e. you launched it from the application modeller, you launched it with a navigate stage or if the application was already launched in some other fashion e.g. manually). To make an identify button appear you need to connect to the application modeller via the attach function (navigate or in the application modeller there's a function for this). In this instance where the question was resolved I suspect there's another issue at play but for others in future if you are struggling with the error when the identify button is greyed out or still says launch that means the object you currently have open is not connected or not attached to a running application.

Answer (score -2):

If you launch application from Google Chrome, then you can get this error because in Google Chrome it's not possible to Spy and launch the applications. Any RPA Tools will support only Internet Explorer

Comment: this is factually incorrect in all angles. RPA tools will support all modern browsers they are not only limited to Internet Explorer (a non-supported browser)